# TensorFlow.js TensorCamera Error: Argument 'x' passed to 'cast' must be a Tensor or TensorLike, but got 'Tensor'

Tags: python, react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor

I'm following the [cameraWithTensors example code](https://js.tensorflow.org/api_react_native/0.2.1/#cameraWithTensors) with React Native
but getting a weird error that the camera tensors are 'Tensor' not Tensor or TensoreLike

```
  handleCameraStream(images, updatePreview, gl) {
    const loop = async () => {
      const nextImageTensor = images.next().value;

      nextImageTensor.toFloat();
      // throws [Error: Argument 'x' passed to 'cast' must be a Tensor or TensorLike, but got 'Tensor']

      nextImageTensor.expandDims(0);
      // throws [Error: Argument 'x' passed to 'expandDims' must be a Tensor or TensorLike, but got 'Tensor']

      // Solved both of it using tf.func but my model is giving a similar error now
      model.predict( tf.expandDims( tf.cast(nextImageTensor, 'float32'), 0) );
      // throws [Error: Argument 'x' passed to 'stridedSlice' must be a Tensor or TensorLike, but got 'Tensor']


      //requestAnimation(loop);
    }
    loop();
  }

return <View>
     <TensorCamera
      // Standard Camera props
      style={styles.camera}
      type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
      // Tensor related props
      cameraTextureHeight={textureDims.height}
      cameraTextureWidth={textureDims.width}
      resizeHeight={640}
      resizeWidth={640}
      resizeDepth={3}
      onReady={handleCameraStream}
      autorender={true}
     />
   </View>
```

Not sure what this error means. I tried printing out a basic tensor and the camera tensor, they both look similar

```
console.log(tf.tensor4d([[
          [[1, 3], [2, 8]],
          [[3, 9], [4, 2]]
      ]]))
// {"dataId": {"id": 247}, "dtype": "float32", "id": 253, "isDisposedInternal": false, "kept": false, "rankType": "4", "shape": [1, 2, 2, 2], "size": 8, "strides": [8, 4, 2]}

console.log( tf.expandDims( tf.cast(nextImageTensor, 'float32'), 0))
// {"dataId": {"id": 246}, "dtype": "float32", "id": 255, "isDisposedInternal": false, "kept": false, "rankType": "4", "scopeId": 14, "shape": [1, 640, 640, 3], "size": 1228800, "strides": [1228800, 1920, 3]}
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Have you found any fix for this? I also get the same Error!